# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'notna'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a csv file with multiple columns containing empty strings. Upon reading the csv into pandas dataframe, the empty strings get converted to *NaN*.

Now i want to append a string `tag-` to the strings already present in the columns but to only those that have some values in it and not on those with *NaN*

this is what i was trying to do:

```
with open('file1.csv','r') as file:
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(file,chunksize=1000, header=0, names=['A','B','C','D'])
        if len(chunk) >=1:
            if chunk['A'].notna:
                chunk['A'] = "tag-"+chunk['A'].astype(str)
            if chunk['B'].notna:
                chunk['B'] = "tag-"+chunk['B'].astype(str)
            if chunk['C'].notna:
                chunk['C'] = "tag-"+chunk['C'].astype(str)
            if chunk['D'].notna:
                chunk['D'] = "tag-"+chunk['D'].astype(str)
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'notna'
```

the final output that i want should be something like this:

```
A,B,C,D
tag-a,tab-b,tag-c,
tag-a,tag-b,,
tag-a,,,
,,tag-c,
,,,tag-d
,tag-b,,tag-d
```

Comment: `notna` is a function. Call it as `notna()` .

Comment: So it seems typo :(

Comment: @jezrael Actually, your answer is fine. If OP was using the correct version, `notna` would have returned a function its truthiness would be evaluated as true. This is actually an XY problem.

Comment: still no improvement I'm still getting the same error when mentioning it as `notna()` @COLDSPEED

Comment: @GabbarSingh Just use `notnull()`

Comment: @coldspeed the difference between `notnull()` and `notna` is that if a field contains `NaN` the `notnull()` function would still return true (as NaN is present there) which is not what i want.

Comment: What? No. Did you read the docs? They are aliases for the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you need [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for add `tag-` to all columns together:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('file1.csv',chunksize=2, header=0, names=['A','B','C','D']):
    if len(chunk) >=1:
        m1 = chunk.notna()
        chunk = chunk.mask(m1, "tag-" + chunk.astype(str))
```

---

You need upgrade to last version of pandas, `0.21.0`.

You can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#na-naming-changes):

> In order to promote more consistency among the pandas API, we have added additional top-level functions `isna()` and `notna()` that are aliases for `isnull()` and `notnull()`. The naming scheme is now more consistent with methods like `.dropna()` and `.fillna()`. Furthermore in all cases where .isnull() and .notnull() methods are defined, these have additional methods named `.isna()` and `.notna()`, these are included for classes Categorical, Index, Series, and DataFrame. (GH15001).
>
> The configuration option pd.options.mode.use_inf_as_null is deprecated, and pd.options.mode.use_inf_as_na is added as a replacement.

Comment: i just checked my version of pandas,
its `0.20.3` so for now i'll try upgrading that and re run the code.

Comment: thanks its working now :) it turns out that pandas `0.20.3` doesn't has pandas series object supporting `notna()` like functions