# How to aggregate across columns in pandas?

Tags: pandas, aggregation

There are 5 members contributing the value of something for every [E,M,S] as below:

```
E,M,S,Mem1,Mem2,Mem3,Mem4,Mem5
1,365,-10,15,21,18,16,,
1,365,10,23,34,,45,65
365,365,-20,34,45,43,32,23
365,365,20,56,45,,32,38
730,365,-5,82,64,13,63,27
730,365,15,24,68,,79,78
```

Notice that there are missing contributions ,,. I want to know the number of contributions for each [E,M,S]. For this e.g. the output is:

```
1,365,-10,4
1,365,10,4
365,365,-20,5
365,365,20,4
730,365,-5,5
730,365,15,4
```

*groupingBy['E','M','S'] and then aggregating(counting) or applying(function) but across axis=1 would do.* How is that done? Or any another idiomatic way to do such ?

Comment: `df.iloc[:,3:].notna().sum(1)
`

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'notna'

Comment: @astro123 it sounds like you are using an older version of Pandas and `.isna()` was not implemented there - see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48331482/4057186), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769508/attributeerror-series-object-has-no-attribute-notna#comment82500279_47769508) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49591368/4057186) for related problems. You might have to use [`.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.notnull.html#pandas-notnull) instead of `.notna`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by @Wen is brilliant and definitely seems like the easiest way to do this.

If you wanted another way to do this, then you could use `.melt` to view the groups in the DF. Then, use `groupby` with a `.sum()` aggregation within each group in the melted DF. You just need to ignore the `NaN`s when you aggregate, and one way to do this is by following the approach in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47170362/4057186) - `.notnull()` applied to groups.

Input DF

```
print df
     E    M   S  Mem1  Mem2  Mem3  Mem4  Mem5
0    1  365 -10    15    21  18.0    16   NaN
1    1  365  10    23    34   NaN    45  65.0
2  365  365 -20    34    45  43.0    32  23.0
3  365  365  20    56    45   NaN    32  38.0
4  730  365  -5    82    64  13.0    63  27.0
5  730  365  15    24    68   NaN    79  78.0
```

Here is the approach

```
# Apply melt to view groups
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['E','M','S'])
print(dfm.head(10))
     E    M   S variable  value
0    1  365 -10     Mem1   15.0
1    1  365  10     Mem1   23.0
2  365  365 -20     Mem1   34.0
3  365  365  20     Mem1   56.0
4  730  365  -5     Mem1   82.0
5  730  365  15     Mem1   24.0
6    1  365 -10     Mem2   21.0
7    1  365  10     Mem2   34.0
8  365  365 -20     Mem2   45.0
9  365  365  20     Mem2   45.0

# GROUP BY
grouped = dfm.groupby(['E','M','S'])

# Aggregate within each group, while ignoring NaNs
gtotals = grouped['value'].apply(lambda x: x.notnull().sum())

# (Optional) Reset grouped DF index
gtotals = gtotals.reset_index(drop=False)
print(gtotals)
     E    M   S  value
0    1  365 -10      4
1    1  365  10      4
2  365  365 -20      5
3  365  365  20      4
4  730  365  -5      5
5  730  365  15      4
```